# Fixing this simple code

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner at coding and I can't fix this code and I'm going crazy. It keeps telling me certain variables were not declared and i'm not sure how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int (a = 0), sum;{
    cout << "This program should read all integer numbers ";
    cout << "to sum until a negative number is entered\n";
    exit(0);
}

while(a < 0) {
   cout << "Enter an integer number: ";
   cin >> a;
   sum += a;
}

cout << "The sum is sum\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and line number?

Comment: `int (a = 0), sum;{
    cout << "This program should read all integer numbers ";
    cout << "to sum until a negative number is entered\n";
    exit(0);
}` What's up with all the curly braces?

Comment: Where did you learn to write code like this? This is the strangest style I've seen in a while. Also the `while` loop will never execute and `sum` is not initialized which would lead to UB on `sum += a;`

Comment: `exit(0)` -> Quit the program right then and there. No code executed after this line

Comment: "certain variables were not declared" -> which ones?

Comment: `int (a = 0)` -> syntax error, remove the parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not initialize sum, so it could start with any value.

You have extra layers of pointless `{ }` around for no reason.

Your final `cout` statement does not actually print the varaible.
Change it to:  `cout << "The sum is " << sum << "\n";`

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 0, sum = 0;
  cout << "This program should read all integer numbers ";
  cout << "to sum until a negative number is entered\n";

  do {
     cout << "Enter an integer number: ";
     cin >> a;
     if (a > 0)
     {
         sum += a;
         cout << "The sum is currently: " << sum << "; but this is not yet the final value.\n";
     }
  } while(a > 0) ;

  cout << "The sum is " << sum << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lots of gotchas with your code.

Issues I found and corrected:

- You have extra parentheses and curly brackets.
- You didn't initialize the variable called sum
- You initialize the variable called a to 0 but your loop will only execute while a is less than 0
- I had to **#include "stdafx.h"** above where you included **iostream**
- The line that says "The sum is sum" - the second sum should be outside the double quotes so that it will be treated as a variable rather than text.

This code works, please compare it to yours:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int a = 0, sum = 0;

    cout << "This program should read all integer numbers ";
    cout << "to sum until a negative number is entered\n";

    while (a <= 0) {
        cout << "Enter an integer number: ";
        cin >> a;
        sum += a;
    }

    cout << "The sum is " << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program will only continue while negative numbers (or zero) are entered.  The question calls for POSITIVE numbers.

Comment: `stdafx.h` is a Visual Studio PCH marker, and is not needed on most compilers.